# Ensure directory exists or create if needed before saving a file

Tags: c#

I have a file name that I am generating from data that is coming from a database.  I need to save the file to a folder location that is coming from a database query.  How do I ensure the path exists so that when I save my file it will not throw an exception about a missing directory?  My file saving code is listed below.  When I call `saveTemp.Save` I am getting an exception because the directory does not exist.

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> newImage = sourceImage.WarpPerspective(mywarpmat, 355, 288, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.WARP.CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS, new Bgr(0, 0, 0));
Image<Bgr, Byte> savetemp = newImage.Copy();

savetemp.ROI = new Rectangle(lokasiX, lokasiY, templatewidth, templateheight);
savetemp.Save(@"D:\Dokumen\Alfon\TA Alfon\CobaFitur\Template\Kotak\" + simpantmp["namakamera"].ToString() +  "Template_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss") + cnt + ".jpg");
```

Comment: I am not sure if I am clear on your question.  Is your question that you want to know how to create a directory?

Comment: Yes it is. I want to create a directory after Kotak\ using this script simpantmp["namakamera"].ToString(). But it always fails. Can you help me ?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code that you are creating a directory.  Is your file save failing with an exception about the directory not existing?

Comment: Yaa. I want to save image but that I mean I want to save that image on directory that I create from that script. For example I choose data "Kamera" on combobox that connect to database. When I click SAVE button, my program will make "Kamera" directory and save image there.

Comment: I edited your question to focus on the issue you were having.  I have also provided an answer for you.  Unrelated to the issue you were having, you should pay attention to the database objects you are creating.  These objects have a `Dispose` method on them (they implement `IDisposable`).  You should enure that you are calling the `Dispose` on them.  One way to do that would be to make use of a `using` block or since you have several of them you could add a `try/finally` pair and call the `Dispose` in the finally block.

Comment: If you want to create a directory, do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to ensure the directory exists before you can save a file to it.  You can do this using the [Directory.CreateDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx) method.  I would also modify your code to use the [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142(v=vs.110).aspx) method to build your path.

```
var fileName = "Template_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss") + cnt + ".jpg");
var filePath = Path.Combine(@"D:\Dokumen\Alfon\TA Alfon\CobaFitur\Template\Kotak", simpantmp["namakamera"].ToString());
Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
saveTemp.Save(Path.Combine(filePath, fileName));
```

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I've tried it into my script and it works. Thanks so much :)